# Android Volley request failing

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, android-volley

I am attempting a Volley request through android to get Oauth credentials using a password grant type. What I am trying works in postman, but is not working in android and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below please find the code I am using:

```
    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    final String url = Constants.OAUTH_URL;

    Map<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
    body.put("grant", "password");
    final JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(body);

    JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest (Request.Method.POST, url, jso,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(final JSONObject response) {
                    //Do something
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    responseText.setText(error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("accept", "application/vnd.TestKitchen.v1+json");
            headers.put("Authorization", BasicAuth.getBasicAuth(Constants.USERNAME, Constants.PASSWORD));
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
```

My OAuth URL is correct, I have verified that several times. So the problem isn't a typo on that end. All of the other fields should still reach my server and give an appropriate response (Be it an error or not), however all requests I send are returning with a 400 response. Anything obvious I am doing wrong that I should fix? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The RequestMethod are you sure is POST? You are trying to get  the credentials.

Comment: I managed to figure it out, the request was fine, I was connected to the wrong network, it couldn't see my dev VM. Once I changed to a different one it worked. I didnt know it was set up like that. Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using this thing?

```
Map<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
body.put("grant", "password");
final JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(body);
```

You can directly put the value in JSONObject

```
JSONObject jso = new JSONObject();
jso.put("grant", "password");
```

In the case of a REST API with a JSON payload, 400's are typically, and correctly I would say, used to indicate that the JSON is invalid in some way according to the API specification for the service.